# Moving Website to new domain and site structure - redirects are only working for subpages not main site

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I've read a ton on creating the proper redirects for my project.  I found some helpful information, but still having an issue.

Ok, I moving a site from one domain unto another. The directory structure has changed as well.

I want the domain to redirect from a .net domain to a .com domain.  Then redirect all of the website sub pages into the correct structure on the new domain.  The subpages are working great, but the home page isn't.  Here the code that I'm using:

```
RewriteEngine on

//301 Redirect Old File

RewriteRule oldsite.net newsite.com [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^p_about.* http://www.newsite.com/about [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^p_linkresources.* http://www.newsite.com/resources [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^p_services.* http://www.newsite.com/services [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^p_events.* http://www.newsite.com/events [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^p_contact.* http://www.newsite.com/contact [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^p_testimonials.* http://www.newsite.com/testimonials [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^p_site_credits.* http://www.newsite.com/resources [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^p_gallery.* http://www.newsite.com/gallery [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^p_gallery.* http://www.newsite.com/gallery [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^p_purchase.* http://www.shop.newsite.com [R=301,L]
```

I greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

This rule:

```
RewriteRule oldsite.net newsite.com [R=301,L]
```

Needs to be:

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.newsite.com/ [R=301,L]
```