# Why are is my homepage not redirecting?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

Read a ton on creating the proper redirects, but still having an issue.

Moving a site from one domain unto another. The directory structure has changed as well. The subpages are working great, but the home page isn't. Here the code that I'm using:

```
  RewriteEngine on

  //301 Redirect Old File

  RewriteRule oldsite.net newsite.com [R=301,L]
  RewriteRule ^p_gallery.* http://www.newsite.com/gallery [R=301,L]
  RewriteRule ^p_purchase.* http://www.shop.newsite.com [R=301,L]
```

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Moving Website to new domain and site structure - redirects are only working for subpages not main site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19284900/moving-website-to-new-domain-and-site-structure-redirects-are-only-working-for)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enabled mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

Because your first rule is wrong:

```
RewriteRule oldsite.net newsite.com [R=301,L]
```

You can only match REQUEST_URI in the RewriteRule.

It should be like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldsite\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://newsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```